# How to pass collection from view to controller in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I want to pass a collection of skills id from my view to controller action, i have a dropdownlist of SKILLS :

```
         <select name="skills">
           <option value="0">Java</option>
           <option value="1">C++</option>
           <option value="2">Fortran</option>
           <option value="3">ASP</option>
         </select>
```

i want that user can select many skills from dropdown and store their value  in a collection ,i.e an array, and then post that array to action in controller as follow [employee and skills have a manytomany relationship]:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddEmp(Employee emp ,IEnumerable<Skills> skills )

 {

   DBCtx db=new DbCtx();
   db.employees.Add(emp);
   var emp_id=db.SaveChanges();

   var employee=db.employees.Find(emp_id);

   foreach(item in skills)
   {
      var skill = db.skills.Find(item);
      employee.skills.Add(skill);
   }
   db.SaveChanges();

   return View();
   }
```

How can  i achieve this ,thanks in advance ....

Comment: A <`select>` only posts back one value - the value of the selected option, and your method need to be `public ActionResult AddEmp(int EmpSkills)` to match the name of your form control. but why are you doing this. Use  a model and bind to your model using the strong types `HtmlHelper` methods (and if you want to post multiple values, then the dropdownlist needs the `multiple` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am wandering for how can i bind it with model in view...

Comment: You have not shown your model! You need a view model with `IEnumerable<int> SelectedSkills` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SkillsList` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSkills, Model.SkillsList)` (or for a multiple select, then `ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSkills, Model.SkillsList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite few options on front end . Razor, Angular, Jquery... To simplfy things in following example i have used Razor view. I dont think you need to pass *Skills* as a strongly type object as you only need *Id* of selected *Skills* . Also in the example i  have the skills list static / hard coded into razor view, ideally it should be bound from backend.

Saying that lets assume our Employee View Model as it follows

```
 public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            SelectedSkills=new List<int>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> SelectedSkills { get; set; }
    }


   public class Skills
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then our Controller (EmployeeController.cs) would be .(please ignore the EF logic after data is bound to class)

```
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View("Employee",new EmployeeViewModel());
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult AddEmp(EmployeeViewModel employee)

            {

                var idOfEmployee=AddEmployee(employee);

                foreach (var item in employee.SelectedSkills)
                {
                    AddSkill(idOfEmployee,item);
                }


                return View("Employee");
            }
       private void AddSkill(int idOfEmployee, int skillId)
        {
            // your EF logic
        }

        private int AddEmployee(EmployeeViewModel emp)
        {
            // your EF logic, get your id of the inserted employee
            return 0;
        }
     }
```

Then our *Employee.cshtml* view could be

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using WebApplication4.Controllers
@model  WebApplication4.Controllers.EmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee";
}

<h2>Employee</h2>

@{var listItems = new List<Skills>
  {
      new Skills { Id = 0,Name="Java" },
      new Skills { Id = 1,Name="C++" },
      new Skills { Id = 2,Name="Fortran" }
  };
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmp", "Employee"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { autofocus = "New Employee" })
    <br/>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSkills,
        new MultiSelectList(listItems, "Id", "Name",@Model.SelectedSkills)
        , new { Multiple = "multiple" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: but how it can select multiple skills from the above Razore view

Comment: Try to run this example. It will render as a select list which will populate the list and allow you to select multiple items within . It will render as a select element .

Comment: it works fine but there is an issue,it require to hold Ctrl key to select mutiple items ,how i can put a check box for selection of each item in list...

Comment: Yup. That is expected behaviour . You need to search how to put  checkboxs with within dropdown or create checkbox list. I believe it is another question. Please don't forget to mark as an answer .

Comment: No problem . Do not forget to mark the answer above  as solution please.You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). Therefore everyone knows that solves the problem